# how to add items into listview without binding WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview

I want to add some items to a listview that is a gridview.
I want to do it through code without implementing the binding option, Simply adding values to set of cells of some sort.
I know it's not the WPF-way but I need this done urgently and I can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for.
I looked at multibind, converters and regular binding but it just won't give me the answer I need for now.

Is it even possible?
If so how can I do it?

Comment: But you have `GridViewColumn` definitions with each having a `CellTemplate`?

Comment: Show us the code you have so far.

Comment: The listview items are dynamic I can't rely on any cell template or gridviewcolumn it all has to be dynamic since I don't know how many columns I'll have there and I don't know how many items I'll have.
This is why I just want to take a cell and insert some data into.
it's for a report so I don't even need it to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use a `DataGrid` instead of a `ListView`? Then you can set `AutoGenerateColumns` to true (is true by default even).

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
```

Then in the code behind do something like this:

```
myDataGrid.Items = new List<MyDataType>();
foreach(var item in itemsToAdd){
    myDataGrid.Items.Add(item);
}
```

or shorter:

```
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = myListOfItems;
```

Comment: Thank you changing the gridview into a datagrid helped me a lot and now everything works!  
it didn't worked quiet as you said but it worked nevertheless.  
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You need index bindings like "[0]".

```
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="lv" />
</Grid>



lv.Items.Clear();
var gv = new GridView();
lv.View = gv;

var columns = new List<string> { "col1", "col2" };
for(int index = 0; index < columns.Count; index++)
{
    gv.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
    {
        Header = columns[index],
        DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("[" + index.ToString() + "]")
    });
}

// Populate list
var row1 = new List<string> { "(1, 1)", "(2, 1)" };
var row2 = new List<string> { "(1, 2)", "(2, 2)" };
lv.Items.Add(row1);
lv.Items.Add(row2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't get hung up on whether to load or not load controls in codebehind. I have worked major Silverlight projects where it was a mixture of both operations.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    lvPrimary.ItemsSource = new List<string> { "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma" };

}
```

With Xaml looking like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFStackOverflow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListView Name="lvPrimary" Width="200"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I like this option but the thing is that my objects aren't simple strings... if it'll work with custom objects too then it'll solve my problem...

Comment: Actually now that I'm thinking of it, it won't help me either because I'll need something that will load the list dynamically.

Comment: @SagiRokach What do you want to show? Give me a class/struct.

Comment: It's ok I figured it out somehow. The answer Roel gave me helped me alot with finding the answer. Thanks anyways.